# how to call activity from application class

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i have got an controller which is inherited by application, i have also set it in manifest file. now i want to call a activity from here. i'm not getting how to do?

Here how i'm trying, but it fails

```
public class SampleApplication extends android.app.Application {

 public SampleApplication() {
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  Context context = SampleApplication.this.getApplicationContext();
     Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setClass(context, MainActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
 }
```

My manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sampleapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="SampleApplication"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sampleapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: An error log would also be useful. Also, it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to call an activity outside of an activity class?

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you are trying to do by simply using the `AndroidManifest.xml` file :

```
<activity android:name="Activity name" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```